# check whether checkboxes are checked in dynamic form does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm developing a webpage that adds checkboxes to form dynamically. I checked that the form is built correctly and is processed correctly by a php file when submitting the form. When submitting the form my validation function checks whether some of the checkboxes are selected and this part does not work. Using `'is(":checked")'` always returns false, also when the checkbox is selected. I strongly suspect the reason is that I define the selectors (`$('#approved_agreement['+ i +']')`) incorrectly when I look at the output of the console within the form submit code (see below): the output shows strange (for me) identical ids (approved_agreement%5B%5D) which however are passed to `$_POST` as a correct array of elements.

How to fix this? When possible I'd like to keep the checkbox id definitions (so I dont need to rewrite the php code).

```
//related form building code
form += '<td> <input type="checkbox" id="approved_agreement[]" name="approved_agreement[]" value="'+ msg[i].name +'"> </td></tr>';
//code for appending form to wrapper

//related validation code
for(var i=0;i<msg.nrofagreements;i++){
        console.log('VALIDATE FORM agreement id: '+'#approved_agreement['+ i +']'); 
        console.log('VALIDATE FORM agreement len: '+ $("#approved_agreement["+ i +"]").length); //show value 0 indicating the element does not exist
        console.log('VALIDATE FORM agreement checked: '+$("#approved_agreement["+ i +"]").is(":checked")); //always shows value false 
         //approved_agreement[]
        if($('#approved_agreement['+ i +']').is(':checked')){
           //some validation code here...
        }//if
}//for

//related code within form submit function
$("#FormAgreementsConfirm").submit(function(event){
    var dataAjax = $( this ).serialize(); //does not work, but when copying the string from the console in line below it odes work.
    console.log('SUBMITTED FORM: '+ dataAjax  ); //shows (when checking the checboxes): approved_agreement%5B%5D=SolarX_10&approved_agreement%5B%5D=SolarX_11
}
```

Comment: What's `msg.nrofagreements`?

Comment: its just a variable with defined int value > 0

Comment: Ok, but your form building code doesn't show us how you change the IDs. You have: `id="approved_agreement[]"` but that would produce identical IDS.

Comment: There are syntax errors in your code, such as not properly closing functions etc. Also, there doesn't seem to be anything preventing the form submit, so assuming it's submitted and the page reloads, what are you really trying to do ?

Comment: @j08691: thnx. How is it possible then that the php file that processes the submitted form receives an array with various (non identical) elements. And how to change the code?

Comment: @adeneo: I only included the parts of code that I think are relevant for the problem, so for example the Submit function shown is not complete (!)